# How to save PDF image in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

My friend send me PDF file. It contains a vectored text image (text is not editable). If I want to open that PDF file in Photoshop, it shows the table and I can pick the size of the image.

Now he wants to make the text in white. So I open the PDF file and use Color Overlay. Then I save it.

The problem is that if I want to open the new PDF file with white text, the table where I can choose the size is not showing. Why? How can I save image in vectors in PDF to let the people choose the size they want?

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - glad to have  you here. Please look around a bit [tour] to get a sense of our community; please also read [ask] and [answer] a question so you know how to frame a query for best responses. Unfortunately, at this point I'm unclear on what's being asked for in your question - what table where a user can choose the size, and of what are they choosing the size? I suggest reading [ask] and then editing your question to clarify it.

Comment: @GerardFalla I mean this - [link](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-z8TzqjZUXoc/UCE-phGSwRI/AAAAAAAAAmA/f9aS_FdNhkM/s1600/Rasterize+1.png)

Sorry, I am not good in English :-)

Comment: Anything you write to comments is totally useless until the question is clear. Edit it!  Congratulations for being still able to resist to write an answer which only contains something that belongs to the question.

Comment: Do you have Illustrator? It's **much** better for editing some PDFs.